# How do I stop WCF from accepting insecure messages?

Tags: c#, wcf, security, soap, ws-security

I'm trying to set up a WCF service with authentication built in. I want to use a custom `UserNamePasswordValidator` to validate the credentials sent in messages.

If I use a standard `wsHttpBinding`, I can get this working without problems using the following config:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
  <binding name="wsHttpBinding_Default" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
    <security mode="Message">
      <message clientCredentialType="UserName" establishSecurityContext="false" negotiateServiceCredential="false" />
    </security>
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                              maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                              maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
  </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

Using SoapUI as my test client, I can get my validator to fire by sending in a Username and Password with the `WSS-Password Type` set to `PasswordText`.

However, this sends the username and password in *plaintext*. And WCF accepts it no questions asked. Here's an example request:

```
POST https://localhost/AuthenticationService/AuthenticationService.svc HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="http://tempuri.org/IAuthenticationService/GetIdentity"
Content-Length: 1060
Host: localhost
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
     <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="true" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-F5AF0BFF1621013979151869690921760">
          <wsse:Username>test</wsse:Username>
          <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">test</wsse:Password>
          <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">LoAQmA/vE33hxFD/nDsBrA==</wsse:Nonce>
          <wsu:Created>2018-02-15T12:15:09.217Z</wsu:Created>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
      <wsa:Action>http://tempuri.org/IAuthenticationService/GetIdentity</wsa:Action>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <tem:GetIdentity/>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

So it looks to me like WCF is ignoring the message security part of this. My understanding is that every message in WCF message security is supposed to be encrypted and signed.

Yes, I know I can just use transport security and call it a day, but that's point to point secure and not end to end. I really don't want credentials visible in plaintext at any point in the process.

How do I stop WCF from allowing these requests?

**EDIT**: I've now specified a client certificate in the service behaviour:

```
<serviceBehaviors>
  <behavior name="AuthenticationServiceBehaviour">
    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    <serviceCredentials>
      <serviceCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" findValue="0e0bab25486677f12fc8abdf1345e5313aec4f67"/>
      <clientCertificate>
        <authentication certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust" trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine"/>
        <certificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" findValue="0e0bab25486677f12fc8abdf1345e5313aec4f67"/>
      </clientCertificate>
    </serviceCredentials>
  </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

I get the same result, WCF is still blindly accepting plaintext messages.

To be clear, if I use a .NET service reference generated client, it correctly does the encryption and signing (confirmed by looking at the trace via fiddler), so message security does seem to be working. However, my issue is that it still allows and responds to unsecured messages.

Comment: Notice that you are contacting `https://localhost`. You username/password are secured by the https connection. The only option, what other secret do Client and Server share?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I already addressed this concern in my question: "Yes, I know I can just use transport security and call it a day, *but that's point to point secure and not end to end*. I really don't want credentials visible in plaintext at any point in the process."

Comment: Then use a ClientCertificate.

Comment: @HenkHolterman done, still get the same result.

Comment: You would use a Certificate _instead_ of a Username.

Comment: That doesn't fit my requirements :(

Comment: For what you want you might have to write some custom behaviour. And then the Server cert may be enough, when you can get its public key. But you would essentially be reinventing the https protocol stack and have to install/maintain it on both sides. .

Comment: But this doesn't make sense. According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/message-security-with-a-user-name-client, message security encrypts and signs messages. Why would it still accept insecure messages in the first place? If I look at fiddler and use a .NET generated client, that correctly encrypts and signs messages, so it is actually doing the message security bit, it's just _also_ not doing it.

Comment: have you tried Fiddler to see if its not encrypted on SOAPUI? I am guessing SOAP UI might be sohwing plain text before sending it to wire

Comment: @Dhawalk I can't seem to get fiddler and soap UI to play nicely, lots of proxy stuff going on it seems, but in soap UI you can view the raw request and if you enable WS-Security it does show encrypted data and not plaintext. I can use fiddler to view comms between the .NET client and the service, though, and I can clearly see when things are encrypted there.